# Cannot use custom non linear colormap in combination with imshow

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, colormap, imshow

I am trying to use a custom colormap to display a ConfusionMatrixDisplay object to have a finer range between 0 and 50 than between 50 and 100 using [this answer](http://protracted-matter.blogspot.com/2012/08/nonlinear-colormap-in-matplotlib.html).

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15, 15)
font = {'family' : 'DejaVu Sans',
    'weight' : 'bold',
    'size'   : 22}
plt.rc('font', **font)


class nlcmap(LinearSegmentedColormap):
    def __init__(self, cmap, levels):
        self.cmap = cmap
        self.N = cmap.N
        self.monochrome = self.cmap.monochrome
        self.levels = np.asarray(levels, dtype='float64')
        self._x = self.levels
        self.levmax = self.levels.max()
        self.transformed_levels = np.linspace(0.0, self.levmax, len(self.levels))

    def __call__(self, xi, alpha=1.0, **kw):
        yi = np.interp(xi, self._x, self.transformed_levels)
        return self.cmap(yi / self.levmax, alpha)


levels = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 100]

cmap_nonlin = nlcmap(plt.cm.viridis, levels)
X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                            random_state=0)
clf = SVC(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
SVC(random_state=0)
predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions, labels=clf.classes_)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm,
                             display_labels=clf.classes_)
lin_cmap = plt.cm.viridis
levels = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 100]
cmap_nonlin = nlcmap(plt.cm.viridis, levels)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = disp.plot(cmap=cmap_nonlin, colorbar=False)
disp.ax_.get_images()[0].set_clim(0, 100)
disp.figure_.colorbar(disp.im_, orientation="horizontal", pad=0.1)
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

Produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 61, in _draw
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1864, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2747, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 646, in draw
    renderer.draw_image(gc, l, b, im)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint8') according to the rule 'safe'
```

It seems the error is related to imshow in conjunction with custom colormap since I can reproduce without sklearn with:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.array([[10, 15], [20, 30]]), cmap=cmap_nonlin)
```

Any idea ? I wish to modify the colormap not the data itself if possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you are reaching into the guts like this, rather than just passing your colormap to `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` directly (it takes a `cmap` kwarg.

Comment: Adding cmap=cmap_nonlin directly to ConfusionMatrixDisplay init doesn't work as it's not recognized as a valid kwargs, I pass it just afterwards to the .plot call but it doesn't work either probably because the cmap is not valid (for some reason which I don't comprehend).

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html

Comment: The reach to the guts happen afterwards for two reasons: moving the colorbar below the plot and fixing the limits of it.

Comment: To move the colorbar below, the [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) has a `location` and a `orientation` parameter, no need to change the color map.  To change the limits, a [BoundaryNorm](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html) could be helpful. Note that the blogpost you link to is almost 10 years old (mentioning code from 2006), and matplotlib has since been extended enormously.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, however changing the position and extremal limits of the colormap doesn't address my question at all. Furthermore I would have been happy if I had found something more recent but all other approaches I could find with custom LinearSegmentedColormaps are very manual although more recent and don't allow to use new visually more appealing colormaps like viridis.

Comment: To add to my previous answer, the code from the blog post verbatim still works even though it is very old. It is just its combination with imshow, which makes the example fail.

Comment: I found a solution, I need to clean-up a bit but it works will post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [matplotlib's doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/custom_cmap.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-custom-cmap-py) on LinearSegmentedColormaps one can do the following to vary the contrast between segments with fast varying segment and slow varying segments.

In this case to answer my question let's have a finer range between 0 and 50 than between 50 and 100 but my solution can be extended to an arbitrary number of different paced segments by changing the levels:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
# A dict with {percentage_of_max_value: percentage_of_variation}. The keys are thus all < 1. and should be in ascending order alongside associated values in the colormap (also ordered and < 1.).
# In this example we have 90% of the variation of the colormap in its first half (until 0.5) and the remaining 10% in its right half
levels = {0.5: 0.9}
# We are not limited to one segment and we can provide for instance the following dict
# levels = {0.4:0.8, 0.5:0.9} to have 80% of variations between 0 and 40% of the colormap max then 10% between 40 and 50% and then the remaining 10% for the rest
cdict = {"red": None, "green": None, "blue": None}
num_values_per_segment = 50
for k, v in cdict.items():
    cdict[k] = []
    # We start the first segment by 0. both for value and cmap_value
    left_val = 0.
    left_cmap_val = 0.
    for val, cmap_val in levels.items():
        values = np.linspace(left_val, val, num_values_per_segment).tolist()
        dynamic_range = np.linspace(left_cmap_val, cmap_val, num_values_per_segment).tolist()
        for i, (v, r) in enumerate(zip(values, dynamic_range)):
            cdict[k].append((v, r, r))
        left_val = val
        left_cmap_val = cmap_val
    # Last segment towards 1.
    values = np.linspace(val, 1., num_values_per_segment).tolist()
    dynamic_range = np.linspace(cmap_val, 1., num_values_per_segment).tolist()
    for i, (v, r) in enumerate(zip(values, dynamic_range)):
        cdict[k].append((v, r, r))
    
# Mapping levels to colormap
cmap = plt.cm.viridis
for k, v in cdict.items():
    if k == "red":
        for i in range(len(v)):
            cdict[k][i] = (v[i][0], cmap(v[i][1])[0], cmap(v[i][2])[0])
    elif k == "green":
        for j in range(len(v)):
            cdict[k][j] = (v[j][0], cmap(v[j][1])[1], cmap(v[j][2])[1])
    elif k == "blue":
        for l in range(len(v)):
            cdict[k][l] = (v[l][0], cmap(v[l][1])[2], cmap(v[l][2])[2])
    else:
        raise ValueError("Color not recognized")
    cdict[k] = tuple(cdict[k])

cmap_nonlin = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('MyCustomCMap', cdict)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
my_image = np.array([[30, 45], [25, 10]])
confusion = ax.imshow(my_image, cmap=cmap_nonlin, vmin=0, vmax=100)
plt.colorbar(confusion, ax=ax)
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

And the resulting `cmap_nonlin` object can be used in conjunction with imshow without any issue:
[image]